# Get EchoNest or Foreign ID from Beats Music ID?

Tags: beatsmusic

I want to get EchoNest metadata for tracks coming from Beats Music.  Beats has a certain track ID, and I am trying to find a way to connect that to a usable track ID for EchoNest, which takes Spotify IDs, MusicBrainz, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Our track IDs are prefixed by us. Currently, there is no way to get information from EchoNest in this way.